# Database schema for rewarding users for their activities

Tags: laravel, database-design

I would like to provide users with points when they do a certain thing. For example:

- adding article
- adding question
- answering question
- liking article

etc.

Some of them can have conditions like there are only points for first 3 articles a day, but I think I will handle this directly in my code base.

The problem is what would be a good database design to handle this? I think of 3 tables.

- user_activities - in this table I will store event types (I use
  laravel so it would probably be the event class name) and points for
  specific event.
- activity_user - pivot table between user_activities    and users.
- and of course users table

It is very simple so I am worrying that there are some conditions I haven't thought of, and it would come and bite me in the future.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well I have found this https://laracasts.com/lessons/build-an-activity-feed-in-laravel as very good solution. Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a forth table that is simply "activities" that is simply a list of the kinds of activities to track.  This will have an ID column, and then in your user_activities table include an 'activity_id' to link to that.    You'll no doubt have unique information for each kind, for example an activities table may have columns like

ID : unique ID per laravel
ACTIVITY_CODE : short code to use as part of application/business logic
ACTIVITY_NAME : longer name that is for display name like "answered a question"
EVENT : what does the user have to do to trigger the activity award
POINT_VALUE: how many points for this event

etc

If you think that points may change in the future (eg. to encourage certain user activities) then you'll want to track the actual point awarded at the time in the user activities table, or some way to track what the points were at any one time.

While I'm suggesting fourth table, what you really need is  more carefully worded list of features to be implemented before doing any design work.   My example of allowing for points awarded to change over time is such a feature that you don't mention but you'll need to design for if this feature is needed.